# An unknown limit with nth root: $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}n(x^{1/n}-1)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

How can I find such a limit:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}n(x^{1/n}-1)$$
I tried using a kind of binomial formulas. But nothing helped so far.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Write the limit as $n(x^{1/n}-1) = \frac{(x^{1/n}-1)}{1/n}$, make substitution $t= 1/n$, this is the definition of the derivative at zero for $d(x^t)/dt$
$$
\lim_{t\to 0^+}\frac{(x^{t}-x^0)}{t-0} = \frac{dx^t}{dt}
$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** We have $x^{1/n}=e^{\log x/n}$. Now use the first two terms of the Maclaurin series of $e^t$.